# select top 1 for each hour (hour wise) using SQL SERVER query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need one query to get some list of records hour wise between two date-time and I want to get last record from each hour, if data does not exist in the data-table then I need to show hour wise  but `importwh` default value should be zero.

result should be like bellow

```
SNO Startdate               enddate                 ImportWH  
1   2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   0  
2   2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   0  
3   2016-12-05 02:00:00.000 2016-12-05 02:59:59.000   0  
4   2016-12-05 03:00:00.000 2016-12-05 03:59:59.000   0  
5   2016-12-05 04:00:00.000 2016-12-05 04:59:59.000   0  
6   2016-12-05 05:00:00.000 2016-12-05 05:59:59.000   0  
7   2016-12-05 06:00:00.000 2016-12-05 06:59:59.000   0  
8   2016-12-05 07:00:00.000 2016-12-05 07:59:59.000   0  
9   2016-12-05 08:00:00.000 2016-12-05 08:59:59.000   0  
10  2016-12-05 09:00:00.000 2016-12-05 09:59:59.000   0  
11  2016-12-05 10:00:00.000 2016-12-05 10:59:59.000   0  
12  2016-12-05 11:00:00.000 2016-12-05 11:59:59.000   0  
13  2016-12-05 12:00:00.000 2016-12-05 12:59:59.000   0  
14  2016-12-05 13:00:00.000 2016-12-05 13:59:59.000   0  
15  2016-12-05 14:00:00.000 2016-12-05 14:59:59.000   0  
16  2016-12-05 15:00:00.000 2016-12-05 15:59:59.000   0  
17  2016-12-05 16:00:00.000 2016-12-05 16:59:59.000   0  
18  2016-12-05 17:00:00.000 2016-12-05 17:59:59.000   0  
19  2016-12-05 18:00:00.000 2016-12-05 18:59:59.000   0  
20  2016-12-05 19:00:00.000 2016-12-05 19:59:59.000   0  
21  2016-12-05 20:00:00.000 2016-12-05 20:59:59.000   0  
22  2016-12-05 21:00:00.000 2016-12-05 21:59:59.000   0  
23  2016-12-05 22:00:00.000 2016-12-05 22:59:59.000   0  
24  2016-12-05 23:00:00.000 2016-12-07 23:59:59.000   0
```

for example data

```
SNO Startdate               enddate                 ImportWH  
1   2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   0.1  
2   2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   0.1  
3   2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   2  
4   2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   1  
5   2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   2
```

should be result like bellow
      SNO   Startdate               enddate              ImportWH

```
1   2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   2 
1   2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   2
```

Comment: Create a calendar table and do a `left join`.

Comment: What does the schema of your source (input) data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to generate this list?

```
    DECLARE   @StartDate DATETIME=CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),110)
    SELECT sv.number AS SNO,DATEADD(hh,sv.number-1,@StartDate) AS Startdate,DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(hh,sv.number,@StartDate)) AS enddate,0 AS ImportWH
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv
    WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND 24
```

```
SNO         Startdate               enddate                 ImportWH
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
1           2016-12-07 00:00:00.000 2016-12-07 00:59:59.000 0
2           2016-12-07 01:00:00.000 2016-12-07 01:59:59.000 0
3           2016-12-07 02:00:00.000 2016-12-07 02:59:59.000 0
4           2016-12-07 03:00:00.000 2016-12-07 03:59:59.000 0
5           2016-12-07 04:00:00.000 2016-12-07 04:59:59.000 0
6           2016-12-07 05:00:00.000 2016-12-07 05:59:59.000 0
7           2016-12-07 06:00:00.000 2016-12-07 06:59:59.000 0
8           2016-12-07 07:00:00.000 2016-12-07 07:59:59.000 0
9           2016-12-07 08:00:00.000 2016-12-07 08:59:59.000 0
10          2016-12-07 09:00:00.000 2016-12-07 09:59:59.000 0
11          2016-12-07 10:00:00.000 2016-12-07 10:59:59.000 0
12          2016-12-07 11:00:00.000 2016-12-07 11:59:59.000 0
13          2016-12-07 12:00:00.000 2016-12-07 12:59:59.000 0
14          2016-12-07 13:00:00.000 2016-12-07 13:59:59.000 0
15          2016-12-07 14:00:00.000 2016-12-07 14:59:59.000 0
16          2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 2016-12-07 15:59:59.000 0
17          2016-12-07 16:00:00.000 2016-12-07 16:59:59.000 0
18          2016-12-07 17:00:00.000 2016-12-07 17:59:59.000 0
19          2016-12-07 18:00:00.000 2016-12-07 18:59:59.000 0
20          2016-12-07 19:00:00.000 2016-12-07 19:59:59.000 0
21          2016-12-07 20:00:00.000 2016-12-07 20:59:59.000 0
22          2016-12-07 21:00:00.000 2016-12-07 21:59:59.000 0
23          2016-12-07 22:00:00.000 2016-12-07 22:59:59.000 0
24          2016-12-07 23:00:00.000 2016-12-07 23:59:59.000 0
```

Mehtod 1，can get other column that not in group, such as SNO：

```
WITH TB(SNO,Startdate,enddate ,ImportWH)AS(

   SELECT 1,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000', 0.1 UNION
   SELECT 2,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000',0.1  UNION
   SELECT 3,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000',2  UNION
   SELECT 4,'2016-12-05 01:00:00.000','2016-12-05 01:59:59.000',1  UNION
   SELECT 5,'2016-12-05 01:00:00.000','2016-12-05 01:59:59.000',2  
)
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Startdate,enddate ORDER BY ImportWH desc) AS rn FROM tb
) t WHERE t.rn=1
```

```
SNO         Startdate               enddate                 ImportWH                                rn
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------
3           2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000 2.0                                     1
5           2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000 2.0                                     1
```

Method 2, Group BY

```
WITH TB(SNO,Startdate,enddate ,ImportWH)AS(

   SELECT 1,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000', 0.1 UNION
   SELECT 2,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000',0.1  UNION
   SELECT 3,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000',2  UNION
   SELECT 4,'2016-12-05 01:00:00.000','2016-12-05 01:59:59.000',1  UNION
   SELECT 5,'2016-12-05 01:00:00.000','2016-12-05 01:59:59.000',2  
)

SELECT Startdate,enddate,MAX(ImportWH) AS ImportWH FROM tb GROUP BY Startdate,enddate
```

```
Startdate               enddate                 ImportWH
----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000 2.0
2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000 2.0
```

Comment: thank u for your  reply,  i want generate like this only but i need  to get last record every hour based...

Comment: Sorry, I don't catch you, can you give more sample data?  you can use row_number function with reverse order the get last record  (rownumber=1)

Comment: data
    SNO Startdate             enddate                 ImportWH  
    1 2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   0.1  
    2 2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   0.1  
    3 2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   2  
    4 2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   1  
    5 2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   2 
     should be result like bellow
      SNO Startdate             enddate              ImportWH  
    1 2016-12-05 00:00:00.000 2016-12-05 00:59:59.000   2 
    1 2016-12-05 01:00:00.000 2016-12-05 01:59:59.000   2

Comment: I had modified my answer, Is it helpful for you?

Comment: hi nolan shang ,thank you for giving answer i have one more issue could you pls open this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033692/not-getting-list-of-hours-data-from-fromdate-to-todate-using-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test table (sno int,startdate datetime,enddate datetime,importwh numeric(5,2))

insert into @test values (1,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000','0.1');  
insert into @test values (2,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000','0.1');  
insert into @test values (3,'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000','2016-12-05 00:59:59.000','2');
insert into @test values (4,'2016-12-05 01:00:00.000','2016-12-05 01:59:59.000','1');
insert into @test values (5,'2016-12-05 01:00:00.000','2016-12-05 01:59:59.000','2');

select '1',startdate,enddate,max(importwh) from @test group by startdate,enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

As my understand, you want to statistic data per hourly.

1, First generate time serial base ID and Day(eacho ID and day will generating relating time serial.
2. Join with your date and group by hour,  and use the max ImportWH value
3. I modified your data,added a new ID.

```
 WITH table1(SNO,ID,IDAliasname,createddate,ImportWH)AS(

        SELECT 48883,'867330022903407','SG2003',CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-12-07 15:15:00.000'),45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48884,'867330022903407','SG2003','2016-12-07 15:46:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48885,'867330022903407','SG2003','2016-12-07 16:02:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48886,'867330022903407','SG2003','2016-12-07 16:17:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48887,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 15:15:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48888,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 15:31:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48889,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 15:46:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48890,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 16:02:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48891,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 16:17:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48892,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 16:33:00.000',45.266
    )
    --SELECT * FROM table1
    SELECT  t.ID,t.IDAliasname,t.StartTime,t.EndTime,MAX(ImportWH) AS ImportWH FROM (
        SELECT d.dt,i.IDAliasname,i.ID,DATEADD(HOUR, sv.number-1,d.dt) AS StartTime,DATEADD(SECOND,-1, DATEADD(HOUR, sv.number,d.dt)) AS  EndTime
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv
        ,(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,table1.createddate,110) AS dt FROM table1)  AS d
        ,(SELECT DISTINCT ID, IDAliasname FROM table1)  AS i
        WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND 24
      ) AS t
    INNER JOIN table1 AS tt ON tt.IDAliasname=t.IDAliasname AND t.ID=tt.ID AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.StartTime,tt.createddate)>=0 AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,tt.createddate,t.EndTime)>=0
    GROUP BY t.ID,t.IDAliasname,t.StartTime,t.EndTime
```

```
ID              IDAliasname StartTime               EndTime                 ImportWH
--------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
867330022903407 SG2003      2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 2016-12-07 15:59:59.000 45.266
867330022903407 SG2003      2016-12-07 16:00:00.000 2016-12-07 16:59:59.000 45.266
867330022903408 SG2004      2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 2016-12-07 15:59:59.000 45.266
867330022903408 SG2004      2016-12-07 16:00:00.000 2016-12-07 16:59:59.000 45.266
```