# Not getting list of hours data from Fromdate to Todate using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am Not getting list of hours get data from Fromdate to Todate using SQL Server.

My Table Data: `table1`

```
SNO     ID              IDAliasname  createddate                ImportWH
48887   867330022903408 SG2004       2016-12-07 15:15:00.000    45.266
48888   867330022903408 SG2004       2016-12-07 15:31:00.000    45.266
48889   867330022903408 SG2004       2016-12-07 15:46:00.000    45.266
48890   867330022903408 SG2004       2016-12-07 16:02:00.000    45.266
48891   867330022903408 SG2004       2016-12-07 16:17:00.000    45.266
48892   867330022903408 SG2004       2016-12-07 16:33:00.000    45.266
```

My query

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTempTable') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #YourTempTable
 GO
 SELECT * 
 INTO #YourTempTable 
 FROM (
     SELECT 
         dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, createddate), 0) as Startdate,
         dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(hour, 1+datediff(hour, 0, createddate), 0)) as enddate ,IDAliasname
         ,ID,ImportWH 
     FROM table1 
     WHERE IDAliasname='SG2004' 
       AND  createddate BETWEEN '2016-12-07 00:00:00.000' 
       AND '2016-12-07 23:59:00') a

select * 
from #YourTempTable

select IDAliasname,ID,Startdate,enddate,max(ImportWH) 
from #YourTempTable 
group by startdate,enddate,IDAliasname,ID
```

I am getting below result

```
SG2004  867330022903408 2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 2016-12-07 15:59:59.000 45.266
SG2004  867330022903408 2016-12-07 16:00:00.000 2016-12-07 16:59:59.000 45.266
```

I need data from  startdate `2016-12-07 00:00:00.000`  to `2016-12-07 23:59:00.000`, I need result like below... Please find data ike bellow

```
 IDAliasname    ID              Startdate               enddate                ImportWH
 SG2004         867330022903408 2016-12-07 00:00:00.000 2016-12-07 00:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 01:00:00.000 2016-12-07 01:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 02:00:00.000 2016-12-07 02:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 03:00:00.000 2016-12-07 03:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 04:00:00.000 2016-12-07 04:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 05:00:00.000 2016-12-07 05:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 06:00:00.000 2016-12-07 06:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 07:00:00.000 2016-12-07 07:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 08:00:00.000 2016-12-07 08:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 09:00:00.000 2016-12-07 09:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 10:00:00.000 2016-12-07 10:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 11:00:00.000 2016-12-07 11:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 12:00:00.000 2016-12-07 12:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 13:00:00.000 2016-12-07 13:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 14:00:00.000 2016-12-07 14:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 2016-12-07 15:59:59.000 45.266
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 16:00:00.000 2016-12-07 16:59:59.000 45.266
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 17:00:00.000 2016-12-07 17:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 18:00:00.000 2016-12-07 18:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 19:00:00.000 2016-12-07 19:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 20:00:00.000 2016-12-07 20:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 21:00:00.000 2016-12-07 21:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 22:00:00.000 2016-12-07 22:59:59.000 0
  SG2004        867330022903408 2016-12-07 23:00:00.000 2016-12-07 23:59:59.000 0
```

Comment: So you want only to show the 24 hour format? Base on your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
-- By using a CTE creating 24 rows for each hour
WITH hoursTable(i, startHour, endHour) as (
    SELECT 1, CAST(CAST('0:00:00' as time) as datetime), cast(cast('0:59:59' as time) as datetime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i+1, DATEADD(HOUR,1,startHour), DATEADD(HOUR,1,endHour)
    FROM hoursTable 
    WHERE i < 24
), 
-- Then you need to grouping your data based on each days
dateTable as (
SELECT IDAliasname, ID, CAST(CAST(createddate AS date) as datetime) justDate
FROM table1
GROUP BY IDAliasname, ID, CAST(CAST(createddate AS date) as datetime)
)
SELECT dateTable.IDAliasname, dateTable.ID, justDate + startHour as Startdate, justDate + endHour as enddate, COALESCE(AVG(table1.ImportWH), 0) ImportWH
FROM dateTable CROSS JOIN hoursTable  -- Here you have combination
LEFT JOIN table1 ON dateTable.IDAliasname = table1.IDAliasname AND dateTable.ID = table1.ID AND table1.createddate BETWEEN justDate + startHour AND justDate + endHour
WHERE justDate + startHour >= '2016-12-07 00:00:00' 
  AND justDate + endHour   <= '2016-12-07 23:59:59'
GROUP BY dateTable.IDAliasname, dateTable.ID, justDate + startHour, justDate + endHour;
```

Comment: thank you for giving answer ,how can i pass fromdate to todate in your query.. (i mean , created between fromdate and Todate)

Comment: I add a `WHERE` to answer, but nit tested, you can use `BETWEEN` also ;).

Comment: hi sha , i need multiple days and between hours

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this

```
    WITH table1(SNO,ID,IDAliasname,createddate,ImportWH)AS(

        SELECT 48887,'867330022903408','SG2004',CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-12-07 15:15:00.000'),45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48888,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 15:31:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48889,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 15:46:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48890,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 16:02:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48891,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 16:17:00.000',45.266 UNION ALL
        SELECT 48892,'867330022903408','SG2004','2016-12-07 16:33:00.000',45.266
    )
    --SELECT * FROM table1
    SELECT  t.ID,t.IDAliasname,t.StartTime,t.EndTime,MAX(ImportWH) AS ImportWH FROM (
        SELECT d.dt,i.IDAliasname,i.ID,DATEADD(HOUR, sv.number-1,d.dt) AS StartTime,DATEADD(SECOND,-1, DATEADD(HOUR, sv.number,d.dt)) AS  EndTime
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv
        ,(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,table1.createddate,110) AS dt FROM table1)  AS d
        ,(SELECT DISTINCT ID, IDAliasname FROM table1)  AS i
        WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND 24
      ) AS t
    INNER JOIN table1 AS tt ON tt.IDAliasname=t.IDAliasname AND t.ID=tt.ID AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.StartTime,tt.createddate)>=0 AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,tt.createddate,t.EndTime)>=0
    GROUP BY t.ID,t.IDAliasname,t.StartTime,t.EndTime
```

```
ID              IDAliasname StartTime               EndTime                 ImportWH
--------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
867330022903408 SG2004      2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 2016-12-07 15:59:59.000 45.266
867330022903408 SG2004      2016-12-07 16:00:00.000 2016-12-07 16:59:59.000 45.266
```